# Multi-agent clustering on a 2D grid

Tags: cluster-analysis, agent

Would like to cluster areas with multiagent system on arbitrary user-generated or procedurally generated 2D grid. *Two examples: [{Rooms}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKuzD.png)   [{Caves}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE9yC.png)*

Non-clusterable walls are black. They should block clustering expansion.

Generic clustering is a bit performance heavy for my application. My environment can change any second and I don't want to recalculate all the grid every time. Will manually destroy nearest clusters where wall\floor environment changes.

**What simple behaviours should be encoded into clustering agents that grow\capture the grid for tightness-interconnectivity?** What are clusters trying to achieve? Cluster quality does not matter very much.

- Consume cells of nearest weaker clusters until you get *25* cells amount? How to stay near *25* and still get pushed for a bit by other stronger clusters?
- Define cluster power\strength by what? By cells amount? By cluster tightness - cells average individual interconnectivity to other cells in a cluster? Width to height ratio?
- Prefer to consume cells that increase interconnectivity? Who is going to consume thin tunnels of lowest interconnectivity then? Is it the weakest pushed out clusters?
- How two big clusters will merge into one if it is more optimal?
  Is it like *"This full merge with neighbour cluster is fruitfull. Merge now. Will discharge bad cells later"* OR *"These individual cells are very fruitfull for me and of weaker cluster. Consume them one by one."*?

**EDIT** Decided to stick to simple flood fill with merging of smallest clusters. [{Looks okay for me}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szkop.png). Possible to break a few clusters and clusterize released cells by conventional clustering algorithms.